# Regex to keep all letters in all alphabets along with digits and underscore (problem on hindi letters)

Tags: javascript, regex, hindi

I found out a regex pattern to remove all non alphabet letters: `\p{L}`

I thus did a regex to remove all non alphabet, non digit and non underscore pattern : `/[^\p{L}\d_]/gimu`

Unfortunately, it does not work with a hindi character like `#फ्रांस` which gives `फरस`

See for yourself here https://regex101.com/r/dnXDK0/1

And please help me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot about diacritics. You need to add `\p{M}` or `\p{Mn}` into the negated character class:

```js
/[^\p{L}\p{M}\d_]/gu
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dnXDK0/2).

Note you do not need the `i` and `m` flags here. `m` redefines anchor behavior, but your regex contains no `^` nor `$`. `i` makes caseful letters match in a case insensitive way, but `\p{L}` matches all letters, upper- and lowercase ones.